# How can I do this subquery?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I've been trying to do a subquery where I get all the messages sent by a user and all the recipients of those messages. But the only thing that I can get so far is an error.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
   UR.NAME,
   UR.SURNAME,
   UR.EMAIL,
   UR.PASSWORD,
   UR.ADRESS,
   UR.CELLPHONE,
   UR.COUNTRY,
   UR.STATE,
   UR.CITY
FROM USERS AS UR
JOIN RECIPIENTBYMESSAGE AS RBM ON RBM.IDRECIPIENT = USERS.IDUSER
WHERE M.IDMESSAGE IN
    ( SELECT M.IDMESSAGE,
             M.BODY,
             M.SUBJECT,
             US.NAME,
             US.SURNAME,
             US.EMAIL,
             US.PASSWORD,
             US.ADRESS,
             US.CELLPHONE,
             US.COUNTRY,
             US.STATE,
             US.CITY
     FROM MESSAGES AS M
     JOIN USERS AS US ON US.IDUSER=M.IDSENDER
     WHERE M.IDSENDER=1 );
```

The problem is in

> WHERE M.IDMESSAGE IN

because M.IDMESSAGE is part of the subquery and I'm calling it from outside
but I don't know what should I do.

If someone have any idea, or any other way not necessarily using subqueries I'll be really thankful.

[Here are my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMYyK.jpg)

Comment: If you're not interested in the other eleven columns, don't SELECT them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
M.IDMESSAGE IN
```

is not in your select table. You can put there one of the columns in your select that you expect it to match

```
M.IDMESSAGE
```

from your

```
inner select.
```

Comment: I did this: WHERE RBM.IDMESSAGE IN  ... and it says that operand should contain one column(s)..

Comment: when using an inner select, your inner query should have not more than one column in your inner select. That column should be the column that you expect it to match the column in the where clause.